# Network requests with callback functions, how to process results from queued requests

Tags: android, queue, offline, android-volley

Using Volley or other networking libraries, there may be needs to add network requests to a queue so that the requests are sent later.

The problem with sending these objects to a queue is that when the objects do get sent, there doesn't seem to be an obvious way to process the results of the network call returned by the server, because this happens in the object's nested callback functions.

My network requests are typically in-line and part of my Activities, Fragments and Services, and the responses use and set variables declared in other parts of those Activities, Fragments and Services. Sometimes altering visual elements in the UI thread.

If these requests are queued and this queue is emptied later when network connectivity is more favorable, I don't seem to have an intuitive way to access the callback methods

Is there a solution to this? Perhaps someone has abstracted this design paradigm out using a bunch of broadcast receivers in the callback methods, or some other event bus.

Thanks for any insight

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My network requests are typically in-line and part of my Activities, Fragments and Services, and the responses use and set variables declared in other parts of those Activities, Fragments and Services. Sometimes altering visual elements in the UI thread.

That's not a very good idea. The activities and fragments, in particular, may have been destroyed while your requests are hanging out in the work queue. At minimum, you are preventing the activities and fragments from being garbage collected. Worse, your results may be going to the wrong UI components (e.g., activity was destroyed and recreated, so the results should go to the new activity instance, but you tied the request to the old activity instance).

> Is there a solution to this?

I'd use an event bus, particularly greenrobot's EventBus for thread flexibility. Have a `Service` manage your work queue, shutting down when the queue empties. The individual operations raise events when the work completes. Things that have interest in those events register and unregister to receive them when those events are relevant (e.g., when the activity/fragment is in the foreground). This way, the work (network I/O) is more decoupled from processing the results of the work (e.g., updating UI).

Comment: I've been looking at greenrobot's EventBus, do you have an example of it in use? I am using Volley

Comment: @CQM: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/EventBus/AsyncDemo https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/EventBus/GreenRobot plus the tutorials from my book (https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/EmPubLite starting around T-12 IIRC).

Comment: thanks, I still have a problem related to Volley though. I want to store my request objects in a List, and remove them when they are able to be posted to the network. These objects still have callbacks within them and I'm not sure how to make them run. One of the callbacks is a network error handler, and that is where I have to add or remove the request objects from the List, but this becomes self referential and my IDE doesn't even like that. Curious how other people do it with Volley

Comment: @CQM: Sorry, I don't use Volley, so I can't help there.